# Calculate the optimal angle for the roof of this dog house.

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, optimization, problem-solving

I'm new to optimization and I'm stuck with the following problem:

Given four square planks 10 cm long each one, without cutting or changing any shape, we use two of them to make the walls and the other two to build the roof (by forming an isosceles triangle). What should be the optimal size of the angle $\alpha$ between the walls and the roof for the house to have the biggest possible volume?

I've spent to much time with this, even though I'm pretty sure the answer is quite simple.

After many trials, the only thing I imagined was that the total volume of the house could be expressed as $$V=2a^2b+abh=200b+10b(\sqrt{100-b^2})$$
whose derivative find a positive local maximum at $b = 5\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{3}$, leading to an optimal angle around $167º$, which is definitely absurd.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT

I'll explain my $a$, $b$ and $h$. If we divide in two de base of the prism that forms the roof, we get two right triangles. $a$ is the the side of each plank, $b$ is the base of both right triangles and $h$ is the hight of those.

Comment: Can you explain your derivation a little more? In fact, what is a,b, and h?

Comment: Try expressing the volume as a function of the plank side length $a$ and one angle $\alpha$, most practically denoting the two identical angles of the isosceles triangle, and take the derivative with respect to the angle. It spares a lot of algebra in my opinion.

Comment: @Bence, I've tried that and I found thing even more complicated. How would you express the total volume referring directly to the angle alpha?

Comment: a, b, and h would seem to be fairly simply trigonometric functions of alpha ...  Oh, and a is just 10, no?

Comment: $V = a^2 \cdot 2 a \cos (\alpha) + a^2 \sin (\alpha) \cos (\alpha) \cdot a$. Taking the derivative yields a quadratic equation with one false (unphysical) and one true root. A quick calculation yielded $\alpha \approx 68.5^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

We can treat this by maximizing the cross sectional area A.

$A = (100 - x^2)^{.5} (20 + x)$ where $x$ is the appex height of the roof

$dA/dx = \frac{-x(20+x)}{(100-x^2)^{.5}} + (100-x^2)^{.5}$

A is max when $dA/dx = 0$

$0 = \frac{-x(20+x)}{(100-x^2)^{.5}} + (100-x^2)^{.5}$

$\frac{x(20+x)}{(100-x^2)^{.5}} = (100-x^2)^{.5}$

$20x + x^2 = 100 - x^2$

$2x^2 + 20x - 100 = 0$

$x^2 +10x - 50 = 0$

This yields a positive $x = 3.660254$

Angle $\alpha = 90 + \sin^{-1}(3.660254/10)$

$\alpha = 111.47$ deg

Comment: I'm happy to see I got to the same result through $V=a^3(2cos(\alpha)+sin(\alpha)cos(\alpha))$, finding your $\alpha$ minus $90°$.

Answer (score -2):

My algebra gives b=√(√7500) or 9.30604 cm, (same as your answer) leading to an (internal) angle of 111.47°--which agrees with @Bence's result.